# Misplaced minitoc

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, counters, minitoc, starred-version

I am struggling to use `minitoc` when I have a starred chapter before the TOC (that I want to appear in the TOC). In the following MWE, the minitoc of Chapter 1 appears under Chapter 2, despite I used `\addstarredchapter` to add the starred chapter:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Phantom}
\addstarredchapter{Phantom}

\dominitoc
\tableofcontents

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{Foo}
\minitoc

\section{FooFoo}
\section{FooBar}

\chapter{Bar}

\minitoc

\section{BarBar}
\section{BarFoo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\dominitoc` before any sectioning command:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\begin{document}

\dominitoc
\chapter*{Phantom}
\addstarredchapter{Phantom}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures
\listoftables
\chapter{Foo}
\minitoc

\section{FooFoo}
\section{FooBar}

\chapter{Bar}

\minitoc

\section{BarBar}
\section{BarFoo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I knew it was as stupid mistake... Thank you very much for the help! =)

Comment: One should alwats read carefully the documentation (I have to say it is not always very clear…).